# FactoryGirl can't access my models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

## Problem

When I try to run `bundle exec rspec`, I always get this error:

```
Failure/Error: before { @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user) }
     
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant User
```

Why can't FactoryGirl see my model? Here are some of my files, for reference:

## Files

My factory:

```
# spec/factories/users.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, class: User do
    email { FFaker::Internet.email }
    password "12345678"
    password_confirmation "12345678"
  end
end
```

My model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :jogs
end
```

My spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'User' do
  before { @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

  subject { @user }

  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:email) }
  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:password) }
  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:password_confirmation) }

  it { is_expected.to be_valid }
end
```

My spec_helper (without all the comments):

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
FactoryGirl.find_definitions

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
```

My rails_helper (without comments):

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|


  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

Comment: Also i believe, you can skip `class: User` part from the factory definition as it will pick up the class by convention.

Comment: Yep, I put that in later, just in case it would help, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

There should be `require 'rails_helper'` instead of `require 'spec_helper'` in your spec.

Comment: Thank you so much, you just changed my life. I promise to be vegan from now on. The problem was I was copying from a dated tutorial that was made before `spec_helper` and `rails_helper` were two separate things.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't intended to make people vegan ). I also had simular issues with outdated code when upgrading rspec.